# How to use Octave from repositories with OpenBLAS compiled on my computer?

Tags: 18.04, shared-library, octave, update-alternatives

It has been [suggested](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?58926#comment33) that using Octave with OpenBLAS compiled in my own computer (rather than precompiled OpenBLAS from repositories) will make the computations faster. I installed GNU Octave (4.2.2) from repositories using apt, and compiled the latest release of OpenBLAS from https://www.openblas.net/.

How to make Octave use this OpenBLAS?

What I have tried so far.

After compiling OpenBLAS, I installed it in `opt/openblas`.

Then I entered the commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libblas.so libblas.so /opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so 50

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 libblas.so.3 /opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so 50

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/liblapack.so liblapack.so /opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so 50

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 liblapack.so.3 /opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so 50
```

Then I configured to use the new OpenBLAS with

```
update-alternatives --config libblas.so 
update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3 
update-alternatives --config liblapack.so 
update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
```

Finally I ran Octave with the new OpenBLAS, but got this error.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.so octave-cli
octave-cli: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to start with all the stuff from Ubuntu repository.
First thing to try is to install `libopenblas-base` package and allow it to provide BLAS and LAPACK alternative, as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base
```

Using our [test script](https://gist.github.com/N0rbert/cfda101b8f0aa326df1edb6beee0076d) we have the following timings for Octave on my i7-3537u:

- 0.42 s -  with simple default `libblas3`, `liblapack3`
- 0.26 s -  with `libopenblas-base` from repository

If you want to optimize it even more - compile the OpenBLAS locally by:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libopenblas-dev

cd /tmp
apt-get source libopenblas-base
cd openblas-0.2.20+ds
DEB_CFLAGS_SET="-march=native -mtune=native" DEB_CFLAGS_SET="-march=native -mtune=native" dpkg-buildpackage  -uc -us -j8

sudo apt-get install ../libopenblas-base_0.2.20+ds-4_amd64.deb ../libopenblas-dev_0.2.20+ds-4_amd64.deb
```

And this will change benchmark results to:

- 0.25 s -  with `libopenblas-base` self-compiled

So it is not useful to compile the optimized library with additional manual optimization.

---

**Conclusion:** I'll recommend to optimize your Octave code first by avoiding for-loops and using vectorized functions as much as possible. This will increase performance tremendously.