# Is it possible to install intel-mkl on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, intel, cpu, intel-cpu

I know that this package is [available via official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/intel-mkl) only from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and in newer versions.

Comment: It may be a good idea to add the [warning](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265802/124466) message to every question related to MKL.

Comment: The official repository is compatible for Ubuntu 18.04 intel https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/installing-free-libraries-and-python-apt-repo.html Then: sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/mkl all main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list' && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv ACFA9FC57E6C5DBE && sudo apt update && apt-cache search intel-mkl-64bit

Comment: @JohanPalych please post your comment as answer. It would be better readable and useful. Also you can provide more details in the answer. Also please describe how to setup system to use these MKL libraries as default. While installed, these MKL libraries are not shown in `update-alternatives` . Please carefully test your solution before posting, binary Intel MKL-based solution may have unexpected bugs which can make situation even worse. While trying to follow you solution I see that `omp_get_num_procs` function is missed, so Scilab and NumPy can't operate.

Comment: Adding the Intel MKL to a Debian / Ubuntu system via one simple script https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb/blob/master/script.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by downloading all the packages from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository using my Docker-based [`deb-download` script](https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download) and install them as follows:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv  7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce

sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
# reboot

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download.git
cd deb-download
chmod +x deb-download.sh
./deb-download.sh ubuntu focal libmkl-full-dev
sudo apt-get install ./storage/*mkl*.deb
```

**Warning:** [be careful](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265802/66509) with these library packages if you need accurate calculation in Octave and similar apps.
To avoid bugs you may want to add `export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=gnu` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

**Note:** removing of MKL is possible by single below command:
`sudo apt autoremove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep mkl | grep 2020.0.166-1 | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: Update: replace `./deb-download.sh ubuntu focal libmkl-full-dev` with `sudo bash deb-download.sh -d ubuntu -r focal -p libmkl-full-dev`